# Missing ubuntu drivers for GT 730 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

I have clean Ubuntu 14.04 and using MSI Nvidia GT730 video card.
By default Ubuntu installed nouveau driver and it is in use right now.
I want to install nvidia proprietary driver, but I do not see them in standard locations:

1. In ubuntu gui tool in system preferences (Software Updates->Additional drivers) drivers are not avaible
2. "sudo ubuntu-drivers devices" and "sudo ubuntu-drivers list" returns empty string
3. sudo lshw -c video:

`*-display
       описание: VGA compatible controller
       продукт: NVIDIA Corporation
       производитель: NVIDIA Corporation
       физический ID: 0
       сведения о шине: pci@0000:01:00.0
       версия: a1
       разрядность: 64 bits
       частота: 33MHz
       возможности: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       кофигурация: driver=nouveau latency=0
       ресурсы: IRQ:45 память:fd000000-fdffffff память:e0000000-efffffff
       память:de000000-
       dfffffff ioport:dc00(размер=128) память:fea00000-fea7ffff`

4. lspci:

> > 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fc8 (rev a1)
> >     
> >     Is it safe to install latest driver downloaded directly from NVidia site?
> >     Any guesses why drivers are not avaible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually install the NVIDIA proprietary drivers for the [GT 730](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/77525/en-us) from the xorg-edgers PPA on 14.04:

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

Comment: Ok, but according to [Ubuntu repo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nvidia-331) and to [Nvidia release notes](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/72250/) there is now support for GT 730

Comment: @MrMNight I've updated my answer accordingly