# how to install video driver for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: video

I need to install video driver for my Ubuntu since I can't make video calls and when I do it state that I got no video driver or somewhat an error

I don't know what to do get this driver ,, I need some help

Comment: what is your video card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Dash by pressing the super key (or Windows key). Type in "software" in the prompt and click on the "Software & Updates" icon. Click on the "Additional drivers" tab and wait for it to load the available drivers. Select whichever driver sounds right for your computer and then click "apply changes".

Comment: No additional drivers available ..

Comment: Do you know what graphics chip your device uses? Whether it's Intel, Radeon or NVidia?

Comment: No I don't .. is there a way to know ? I got Lenovo T540p laptop

Comment: Looks like your laptop has a GeForce GT 730. Follow the instructions in the answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/524648/missing-ubuntu-drivers-for-gt-730-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I have did it and install .. still nothing have changed no video driver installed

Comment: Type `lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'` in terminal to detect which video driver is currently in use. See this answer for more details: http://askubuntu.com/a/254877/143396

Comment: I got an output .. ( Kernal driver in use: i915 )

Comment: That's an intel driver, which suggests your nVidia driver has not been loaded. Typing `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` just to double check.

Comment: it doesn't show anything after writting that

Comment: Sorry, I'm going to leave this for someone else at this point. I'm not sure why your nVidia driver is not being detected.